# Sharing a common text file in a java web application

Tags: java, performance

I'm currently working on a Java web application that does heavy calculations on the server side. I am trying to create a mapping system similar to Google maps.

Clients send queries to the server through Java Servlets. For every instance, a huge multidimensional map array variable is created. I think this may be inefficient in terms of speed and RAM usage on the server computer.

So is it possible for all instances to share access to same variable in memory so that the same variable won't be created over and over again?

The map array variable is a huge text file, and currently the text file is reopened for every request.

I was thinking about using a global constant variable, but I also want this shared variable to be modifiable at run time so that the server doesn't have to be restarted/recompiled in order to change the array data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Create a **Singleton EJB**. Annotate your EJB with `javax.ejb.Startup` so that when the server starts, your bean starts too. Populate your variable in EJB *init* method. Any web component would be able to access that singleton EJB. Singleton EJB makes sure that there is only 1 copy exists no matter what. Singleton EJB won't be stopped by the container unless there is an error.

**2)** If you can't implement EJB, then create a class which implements `ServletContextListener`. So when the `ServletContext` is *initilized*, `ServletContextListener` class will get a call back, where you set your variable.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in great detail! The init of the ServletContextListener is exactly what I was looking for! I'm not familiar with singleton EJB and annotations, so I'll be trying those out some other time. But thank you for giving multiple solutions!

Answer (score 0):

use static variables to share all instances, but make sure if your doing any update to synchronize these update. 
or
you can store the variable in the servletcontext which is shared between all clients

Comment: Static variable ? in what ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I completely forgot about the uniqueness of static variables.